# grepl does not seem to work with perl = TRUE

Tags: r, grepl

the below regex seems to work fine in this [***demo***](https://regex101.com/r/XTFN3N/1), but not in `R grepl` per below:

```
dat <- c("Chief Executive",
         "Chief Executive Officer",
         "Human Resources Director",
         "Head",
         "Chief Operating Officer",
         "Global Director HR Business Partnering",
         "Group Finance Director",
         "HR Director",
         "Chief People Officer",
         "Country Head, UK and Ireland",
         "Head of People",
         "Head of People and Culture",
         "UK Country Head",
         "Head of HR")

RE <-  "^(?!.*(?:HR|People)).*\b(?:Chief|Head)\b.*$"
grepl(RE, dat, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
```

Out:

```
> grepl(RE, dat, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

the regex was taken from this question:
[regex to match conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750422/regex-to-match-conditionally)
This is puzzling as i'm using `perl=T`... What else could be an issue?

Comment: Because R uses double \`\\\` for escaping. Try with `RE <-  "^(?!.*(?:HR|People)).*\\b(?:Chief|Head)\\b.*$"`

Comment: great, for some reason i assumed `perl=T` took care of that